# In MediaWiki, how to make a template that will not display anything when variable is null?

Tags: mediawiki

I defined a template that should link to a page when the the variable is non-empty:

```
[http://openlibrary.org/works/XXX/{{{ISBN}}} {{{ISBN|}}}]
```

But what's not working as perfectly is that when the variable `ISBN` is not given a value, a non-functional link is still displayed. How to improve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you have the [ParserFunctions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ParserFunctions) extension, you can use the `#if` function, as documented on [MediaWiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Extension:ParserFunctions#.23if):

> This function evaluates a test string and determines whether or not it is empty. A test string containing only white space is considered to be empty.
>
> `{{#if: test string | value if test string is not empty | value if test string is empty (or only white space) }}`

The template you described would look something like this, that is, the link is only displayed if the ISBN parameter is not empty:

```
{{#if: {{{ISBN|}}} | [http://openlibrary.org/works/XXX/{{{ISBN}}} {{{ISBN|}}}] }}
```